# Clojure return value from a loop

Tags: clojure

I want to calculate intersection points. This works well, but I want to store the points in a vector that the function should return.

Here is my code:

```
(defn intersections
  [polygon line]

  (let [[p1 p2] line
        polypoints (conj polygon (first polygon))]

    (doseq [x (range (- (count polypoints) 1))]

      (println  (intersect p1 p2 (nth polypoints x) (nth polypoints (+ x 1))))
)))
```

Instead of `println` I want to add the result to a new vector that should be returned. How can I change it?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a `for` loop.  The `doseq` function is meant for side-effects only and always returns `nil`.  An example:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn intersect-1
  [numbers]
  (let [data-vec (vec numbers)]
    (vec
      (for [i (range (dec (count numbers)))]
        {:start (nth data-vec i)
         :stop  (nth data-vec (inc i))}))))
```

The above way works, as seen by the unit test:

```
(dotest
  (is= (intersect-1 (range 5))
    [{:start 0, :stop 1}
     {:start 1, :stop 2}
     {:start 2, :stop 3}
     {:start 3, :stop 4}])
```

However, it is more natural to write it like so in Clojure:

```
(defn intersect-2
  [numbers]
  (let [pairs (partition 2 1 numbers)]
    (vec
      (for [[start stop] pairs]
        {:start start :stop  stop} ))))
```

With the same result

```
  (is= (intersect-2 (range 5))
    [{:start 0, :stop 1}
     {:start 1, :stop 2}
     {:start 2, :stop 3}
     {:start 3, :stop 4}]))
```

You can get more details on [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template) (including a big documentation list!).  See especially the Clojure CheatSheet!

**Side note**:  The `vec` is optional in both versions.  This just forces the answer into a Clojure vector (instead of a "lazy seq"), which is easier to cut and paste in examples and unit tests.

Comment: thx a lot for your detailed answer. it helped me solve my problem and Unterstanding Clojure a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of for-loop, a `map` would be more idiomatic.

```
(defn intersections
  [polygon line]
  (let [[p1 p2] line]
    (vec (map (fn [pp1 pp2] (intersect p1 p2 pp1 pp2)) polygon (cdr polygon)))))
```

or:

```
(defn intersections
  [polygon line]
  (let [[p1 p2] line]
    (vec (map #(intersect p1 p2 %1 %2) polygon (cdr polygon)))))
```